# Exception Handling in SSIS Script Task

Tags: ssis

Is it possible to redirect the Exceptions occurred to another table/log, in Script Task ? If so, How is it to be done ?

Comment: Are you already using logging in your SSIS Package?

Comment: yes. But I just thought to try in a different way

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do anything in a script task that you can do in vb.net or C#.  But if you are doing so much in a script task, why do you need to use SSIS.  SSIS handles most things like exception logging, error handling, etc fairly well.  You should use SSIS for what it does and only sparingly go to a script task when you are trying to do something specific that SSIS does not handle well.  To have an SSIS package that simply has a Script Task in it that handles everything, would be like having a vb.net program that calls a C# dll for all of the work.  If you wrote everything in C# why would you need the vb.net wrapper?

Comment: Amen to that.  I am on my second day of troubleshooting a pesky little SSIS package containing several script tasks that we're migrating from SSIS2008 to SS2012.  I'm increasingly of the opinion that SSIS was not an appropriate platform to pick in the first place.